# How to update state if I have props coming from parent component in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to get updated textbox value if I have props from parent component.

Here is my code -

```
const initialState = {
    name: "",
    age: 0
  }

const UserAdd = (props:any) => {
    const {selectedUser} = props;
    
    

    const [state, setState] = useState<any>(initialState);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onChangeValue = (event:any) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setState((prevState:any) => (
            { ...prevState, [name]: value }
            ));
    }

    

    const onSubmit = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name } = e.target;
        dispatch(addUser(state.name, state.age))
        setState({ ...initialState });
    }

    const onUpdate = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name } = e.target;
        console.log(state.name , state.age , "name-age")
    }
    
   

    return (
        <div className="add-user">
            <hr />
            <h2>Add User</h2>
            <hr />
            { selectedUser ? 
            (<form className="form-inline">
                <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="email2" placeholder="Enter user name" name="name" value={selectedUser.name} onChange={onChangeValue} />
                <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="pwd2" placeholder="Enter user age" name="age" onChange={onChangeValue} value={selectedUser.age} />
                    
                <button type="submit" onClick={onUpdate} className="btn btn-primary col-md-2 mb-2">Update</button>
            </form>)
            :
            (
                <form className="form-inline">
                <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="email2" placeholder="Enter user name" name="name" value={state.name} onChange={onChangeValue} />
                <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="pwd2" placeholder="Enter user age" name="age" onChange={onChangeValue} value={state.age} />
                    
                <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-primary col-md-2 mb-2">Submit</button>
            </form>
            )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserAdd;
```

When There is no props i.e (no selectedUser), Then state change working fine and I am able to dispatch action as well. But When Props(selectedUser) is available, then I am unable to edit textbox field & unable to get updated state. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

look deeper into your code.. there is different forms when `selectedUser` is not falsy...
when there is selected user:

```
value={selectedUser.name}
```

shouled be like the other form's input:

```
value={state.name}
```

u also need to add useEffect to change the state when the prop is being changed, u can do it like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
        setState((prevState:any) => (
              { ...prevState, name: selectedUser.name}
        ));
    },[selectedUser.name])
```

the `useEffect` then will be executed whenever any item of the dependency list will be different from the last render (in this case each time the selectedUser.name is being changed)

Comment: exactly, that is what I am trying to ask if we have selectedUser ten how to update state ?

Comment: Sure I am waiting

Comment: It is saying Unexpected use of 'name' in useEffect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222008/discussion-between-anurag-mishra-and-adir-abargil).

Answer (score 0):

In case there is `selectedUser`, the `value` attribute of input field should be reactive. Currently, it is set to props that won't react to `onChangeValue` handler. Use state in the `value` attribute (state.name /state.age) and initialize states with `selectedUser` props value. It might look like below -

```
const initialState = {
    name: "",
    age: 0
  }

const UserAdd = (props:any) => {
    const {selectedUser} = props;
    //Button text would be Update or submit that depends on selectedUser.
    const btnText = selectedUser ? "Update" : "Submit";
    //If it founds selected user then set to it otherwise go with initialState
    const [state, setState] = useState<any>(selectedUser || initialState);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const onChangeValue = (event:any) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setState((prevState:any) => (
            { ...prevState, [name]: value }
            ));
    }

    const onSubmit = (e:any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { name } = e.target;
        dispatch(addUser(state.name, state.age))
        setState({ ...initialState });
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="add-user">
            <hr />
            <h2>Add User</h2>
            <hr />
            <form className="form-inline">
                <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="email2" placeholder="Enter user name" name="name" value={selectedUser.name} onChange={onChangeValue} />
                <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="pwd2" placeholder="Enter user age" name="age" onChange={onChangeValue} value={selectedUser.age} />
                    
                <button type="submit" onClick={onUpdate} className="btn btn-primary col-md-2 mb-2">{btnText}</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserAdd;
```

Once you set it up like this you don't need to render forms conditionally. you only need one form. I have added a few comments as well. I have created a working POC here https://codesandbox.io/s/propstostate-react-ssirn

Comment: @AnuragMishra see the edited answer. Also, i have added a codesandbox very similar to your problem statement.